# Парсинг строки в массив JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как можно из строки, например - `let str = "привет <a href="#" target="_blank">*любая ссылка*</a> пока"` сформировать массив. Пробовал метод split, где в параметр передавал регулярку, но строка парсилась неверно. Нужно, чтобы массив формировался отдельно словами и DOM-узлами. Конкретно DOM- узел должен быть `<a></a>`.Есть идеи? Спасибо

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way)

Comment: Приведите Ваше регулярное выражение и пример массива, который хотите получить

Comment: let str = "привет <a href="#" target="_blank">*любая ссылка*</a> пока" из этого должен получится массив - [привет, <a href="#" target="_blank">*любая ссылка*</a>, пока] . Я пробовал юзать str.split('/\s+</'), но split при нахождении '<' удаляет этот символ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вам уже заметили в комментариях, парсить HTML регулярками считается ненадёжным.

Если не посчитаете это чрезмерным средством, можно воспользоваться [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
let str = 'привет <a href="#" target="_blank">*любая ссылка*</a> пока';

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');

const nodes = [...doc.body.childNodes]
  .map(node => node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ? node.nodeValue : node.outerHTML);

console.log(nodes);
```

Если уж так необходимо решать при помощи регулярок, можно рискнуть так:

```js
let str = 'привет <a href="#" target="_blank">*любая ссылка*</a> пока';

const nodes = str.split(/(?=<\w)|(?<=<\/\w+>)/);

console.log(nodes);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает

Comment: Но учтите, что регулярка не будет работать правильно, если будут вложенные элементы.